# Markdown for airport codes

Tags: feature-request

Do we have any special markup for airport codes? Is there way I can mark up, say, "LHR" in the body of a question, such that a reader can easily mouse-over or click on it to discover the full name of the airport?

Failing that, do we have a recommended style for consistently formatting airport codes or is everyone happy to have them looking like normal text?

Comment: While MenoTalk is correct, I do like the idea. Makes it more interactive, and doesn't have to rely on the correct tag being there.

Comment: Since this is marked as a feature request, I'll give you the standard reply: please show some examples of cases where having the feature is needed or would make a big difference. I like the idea at first glance, but it would be a fair amount of work to create, it's really specialized, and without doing much research I feel like it could easily be worked around with different wording in posts (e.g. "I'm flying into LHR (London Heathrow) on Oct. 17, and...").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid no such feature exists. Anyway it is not really needed, airports in question are usually also tagged, and the tag itself when hovered will show a tooltip with a brief wiki about the tag, whether it is airport or not.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by MeNoTalk's answer, let me suggest you use tag markup in the question, like this:

I'll be travelling to [lhr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lhr) soon and ....

The markup is `[tag:lhr]` and it does the styling, makes it a link to questions tagged with that, but alas doesn't show the tag wiki on the spot.

Comment: +1 Nice suggestion, I guess we should suggest that the tag wiki shows on tags within questions and answers.